# How can I format JS object array for PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have this HTML form where I push each row into an array as objects and send it to PHP to process.

I manage to get ids in responding but I also get ***error*** 
`Undefined offset:1 and Trying to get property of 'id' of non-object`

I didn't quite understand why. I know that the first error appears when I have the unmatched key in my object but in this case, I don't have any. I thought maybe it's happening because of the structural differences of object arrays between js and PHP. I will be appreciated for any help.

***JavaScript and AJAX***

```
      $(function(){
          $(".checkBoxClass").on("click", function() {
              invoices = [];
              $("table > tbody > tr").each(function () {
                  var $tr = $(this);
                  if ($tr.find(".checkBoxClass").is(":checked")) {
                      invoices.push({
                          id: Number($tr.find("#id").text()),
                          name: $tr.find("#adSoyad").text(),
                          cariKodu: $tr.find("#cariKodu").text(),
                          adres: $tr.find("#adres").text(),
                          il: $tr.find("#il").text(),
                          ilce: $tr.find("#ilce").text()
                      });
                  }
              });
                  console.clear();
              console.log(JSON.stringify(invoices));
              });
          });

          function sendInvoice(){
              var invoicesArray = JSON.stringify( invoices );
              $.ajax({
                  type: "POST",
                  url: "invoice.php",
                  //contentType: 'application/json',
                  data: {data : invoicesArray}, 
                  success: function(respond){
                      alert(respond);
                  }
              });
          }
```

***Server Code PHP***

```
    $data = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['data']));

    for($i=0; $i<=count($data); $i++){
        echo($data[$i]->id);
        echo"\n";
    }
```

Comment: Which type of output you want. please add your expected output

Comment: I will actually loop through the array and put object props into related fields in xml and send it to another API. What I want is to understand why I get those errors and how to get rid of them.

Comment: I think your loop should be like this `for($i = 0, $i = count($data); $i <= $i; $i++){}` this will count once, but in your loop its counting again and again.

Comment: @Dilek it's infinite loop

Comment: Could you provide `var_dump($data)` here.

Comment: @Dmitry This is what I get then

`array(1) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#1 (6) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(224)
    ["name"]=>
    string(28) "SIM CAM SANAYI VE DIS TIC AS"
    ["cariKodu"]=>
    string(8) "HE7F61WV"
    ["adres"]=>
    string(20) "SANAYIYOLU CAD MO:27"
    ["il"]=>
    string(8) "ISTANBUL"
    ["ilce"]=>
    string(6) "PENDIK"
  }
}`

Comment: You only have one array element here, but you are trying to loop over two. `$i<=count($data)` needs to be `$i<count($data)`

Comment: @04FS can't believe I haven't seen it! Thank you, problem solved :)